# Informatica data lineage

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I am new to Informatica Powercenter. My company has a ETL implemented in Informatica. What's the best (easiest) way to find the source table and fields mapping to the target table and fields? The ETL logic is rather complicated involving multiple tier architecture:

E.g.

```
    mapping 1: table a, table b - table c
    mapping 2: table c, table d - table e
```

Now need to find where the fields in e is ORIGINALLY coming from. They should be coming from table a, b, d since c is intermediate table. And I will need to work out a mapping of fields in e with fields in original tables.

I know this could be done manually by looking at the mappings in mapping designer, but the example here is simplified, the real ETL is much more complicated. And the task is to analyze all target tables in a database.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using the app I once created: [XMLAnalyzer for PowerCenter](https://xmlanalyzer.maciejg.pl/). It's capable to perform source-to-target analysis for individual mappings as well as complete workflows.